# Issue on Loading Required Library With dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I have dojo js file and I have saved the `ClusterLayer.js` in all directories like

```
root --> ClusterLayer.js
root --> extras/ClusterLayer.js
root -->js/extras/ClusterLayer.js
root -->js/ClusterLayer.js
```

and the file is like

```
    require([
    "esri/map",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/geometry/Geometry",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils",
    "extras/ClusterLayer",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/Color",
    "esri/InfoTemplate",
    "esri/dijit/HomeButton",
    "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
    "dojo/parser",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/SpatialReference",
    "esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",

    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, arrayUtils, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, Geometry, Point, webMercatorUtils, ClusterLayer, Graphic, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, Color, InfoTemplate, HomeButton, OverviewMap,   parser, GraphicsLayer, SpatialReference, PopupTemplate)
```

but still getting error

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: what is the 3.14 in the url?

Comment: You're trying to load your `Clusterlayer.js` file from the server at js.arcgis.com. You should be loading it from your local server. Hard to see what's going on because you didn't share your HTML.

Comment: Most likely you did not define the package map for "extra". See: https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/

Answer (score 1):

There is an ArcGIS tutorial that discusses doing [exactly this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_javascript_classes.html#step4).  (Jump to step 4; apparently the link fragment doesn't navigate within the page correctly.)

I would note, though, that generally setting `packages` is preferable over `paths`, so instead of setting this:

```
paths: { extras: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/extras" }
```

I would set this:

```
packages: [
    { name: "extras", location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/extras" }
]
```

(See also Dojo's [CDN tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/cdn/index.html) which explains basically the same situation.)

Both should roughly have the same effect in this case.